# Update where column value is True AND timestamp column is MAX

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, sql-update

I want to update the single latest row where a `boolean` column value is `True`.

`boolval` and `timestamp` are my two columns in table.

```
boolval  timestamp
--------------------------------
True     1998-01-02 00:00:00.000    
False    1999-01-02 00:00:00.000    
False    2000-01-02 00:00:00.000    
True     2001-01-02 00:00:00.000 --(Given this data, I want to update this row)    
False    2006-01-02 00:00:00.000
```

Consider this pseudocode for what I want to do..

```
UPDATE tablename SET boolval='False' WHERE boolval='True' AND timestamp IS MAX;
```

`AND timestamp IS MAX` is incorrect syntax and causes the statement to be invalid.

Comment: mySQL or SQL Server?  They are different

Comment: Are you using both SQL Server and MySQL? (Don't tag products not involved...)

Comment: Is this a one-time task, or something that is going happen frequently?

Comment: @jarlh Talkative aren't they...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
UPDATE Table1 
SET boolval='False' 
WHERE boolval='True' 
AND timestamp = (SELECT MAX(timestamp) FROM Table1 where boolval='True');
```